# Autocomplete columns in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm a very new in Excel 2010! Well, I have a book with 3 column (A,B,C). A contains Id(1,2,3...100), B contains the reference numbers (any unique integer numbers) and C - with empty cells. So, I want to get in C column something like that (http://localhost/img/.jpg) I meant I want to get an autocomplete text column C with the data from column B in the 100 cells range

Could you please explain how I can do that?
P.S. I start the range count from a second cell because first cell contains a text-header data.

Comment: your image does not work. Please explain what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish. Or at least give an example.

Comment: Please upload your image to an image sharing site such as imgur.com; your question is not clear.

Comment: for instance
http://imgur.com/2YW1uAb

Answer (score 2):

This should join everything perfectly.

```
=C2&B2&".jpg"
```

Copy the formula down the column and it will auto-fill for the rest.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.